# minifyEnabled true and shrinkResources true keep crashing

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, constructor, android-gradle-plugin

How can I fix this error?

**This callable does not support a default call**

Here is my gradle file :

```kotlin
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and here is an error msg :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 20810
cm.n0: This callable does not support a default call: public constructor MyModel(@wk.q platform: c.u? = ..., @wk.q latestVersion: kotlin.String? = ..., @wk.q minimumVersion: kotlin.String? = ..., @wk.q committedDate: java.time.LocalDateTime? = ...) defined in MyModel[c@b3e88db]
    at cm.e.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:48)
    at yk.a.a(KotlinJsonAdapter.kt:47)
    at xk.a.a(NullSafeJsonAdapter.java:3)
    at wt.c.a(MoshiResponseBodyConverter.java:8)
    at vt.p.c(OkHttpCall.java:21)
    at vt.p$a.b(OkHttpCall.java:1)
    at ep.e$a.run(RealCall.kt:13)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
```

and I tried below but error occurred

```
-keep class MyModel { *; }
```

Comment: You should refer proguard rules https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code you have to specify some classes to not be excluded while building

Comment: @trinadhthatakula Thank you I fixed it ! I tried `-keep class`, `-keep interface` and `-keepclassmembers enum`